# Git - cannot either merge or rebase when merging feature branch onto updated develop

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

So I am stuck in the baffling endless loop of merge conflicts when I am trying to merge my feature branch onto my updated develop branch.

I have a feature branch that is based on an old commit from develop branch. Develop branch in the meantime, has been updated and is on a different commit. I want to apply and 'merge' the changes from the feature branch onto the develop branch and all the conflicting files should be based on the changes made in the feature branch.

That state I am currently at: I have fetched and successfully merged changes from origin/dev onto my local dev branch. Now I want to merge the feature branch onto the dev branch. However, when I try to

```
git checkout dev
git merge feature-branch
```

the command results in the following:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        gulpfile.js
        package-lock.json
        package.json
```

When I try to rebase the feature branch based on the dev branch:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase dev
```

The error:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

Note that both of the branches are up-to-date respectively. Dev branch is up-to-date with origin/dev with nothing to commit and with the working tree clean.
Same goes for the feature branch, although the feature branch has never been pushed to repo and only exists locally.

The desired result is to apply changes made in the feature branch onto the dev branch and use feature changes on all conflicting files

Also, note that this is not a professional environment. We have not really decided on a specific strategy as our git knowledge is still limited. But this is an error (obviously human one) that has occurred several times already, so I am glad for any tips for the future.

EDIT: So I managed to fix the specific problem by pushing the feature branch to the repo and merged it using pull request. However, this did not fix (or answered the actual issue of having merge conflict because of local changes when there aren't any)

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know how painless the merge or rebase would actually be, but your current error message is pointing to something else:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        gulpfile.js
        package-lock.json
        package.json
```

There are a number of ways to clean your working directory so that the merge would complete.  One option would be to just use `git stash`.  After typing `git stash`, you would see Git pause for a bit while it goes off and commits your working directory behind the scenes.  Once it finishes, type `git status` to verify that the working directory be clean, and then try to do the merge again.  After the merge is complete, you can `git stash apply` the changes to bring back your working directory to the state in which it was before the merge.

But this assumes that you actually want the changes to these files.  The files seem like they might be artifacts of Node or some other Javascript tool, and not really part of your main codebase.  In this case, you could just checkout the files to remove them from the working directory:

```
git checkout -- gulpfile.js
git checkout -- package-lock.json
git checkout -- package.json
```

Comment: I already tried to git stash with no success, but I like the second option, beacause I do not need to keep the changes from develop branch. What would would be the course of action though? I mean what is going to happen when I checkout these files and when should I do it?

Comment: OK...if you stashed and the changes came back, then maybe it is because some other process is bringing them back.  If so, then `git checkout --` also may not work as you expect.

Comment: So I just go on to the dev branch, checkout these files with the command you provided and then apply merge?

Comment: Yes, that _should_ work, but that assumes again that nothing else is mucking with these files to add changes to them.

Comment: ```git checkout --``` does not seem to do anything

Comment: Then find out what is changing these files.